# Trouble with Delete Action

Tags: visualforce, outputlink

So I have an outputLink that is styled to look like a button. It is essentially a delete button so whenever it is pushed a selected custom object (Relationship_Detail__c) is deleted. The button functions somewhat properly because the object is indeed deleted. However I am receiving an odd URL message saying that the URL no longer exists. I will attach a screenshot of the error message and here is the outputLink code

```
<apex:outputLink styleClass="btn" target="_top" value="{!URLFOR($Action.Relationship_Detail__c.Delete, selectedDetail)}" rendered="{!IF(BEGINS(selectedId, '00'), true, false)}">
    <apex:outputText value="Delete"/>
</apex:outputLink>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing from an outputLink to a commandLink and making a delete method within my extension controller.

```
<apex:commandLink style="font-size:125%" styleClass="btn" action="{!DeleteRelationship}" value="Delete" rendered="{!IF(BEGINS(selectedId, '00'), true, false)}" reRender="Everything"/>
```

and the method

```
public void DeleteRelationship(){
  delete selectedDetail;
  boolean foundIt = false;
  Integer i=0;
  Integer relationshipSize = relationships.size();
  while(!foundIt && i<relationshipSize){
      if(relationships[i] == selectedDetail){
          foundIt = true;
          relationships.remove(i);
      }
      i += 1;
  }
  selectedDetail = null;
  selectedId = null;
}
```

Essentially I make a database call to remove the custom object from the database, then I search through the list of all of the custom objects, find the one I am looking for and remove it from the list. I finish by setting the variables that held information on that object to null